# SAS PROC REPORT

Tags: report, sas

I have the following dataset (fictional data):

```
data have;
    input team $ goals_12 goals_13 var_12_13;
cards;
LIV 20 25 .25
MNC 21 24 .14
MUN 30 25 -.17
ARS 10 12 .20
CHE 23 23 0
EVE 20 18 -.1
TOT 10 0 -1
;
run;
```

I am trying to create a report for this dataset.  Here is what I have:

```
proc report data=have;
    column team goals_12 goals_13 var_12_13;
    define team / 'Team';
    define goals_12 / analysis '2012 Goals';
    define goals_13 / analysis '2013 Goals';
    define var_12_13 / order analysis format=percent. mean "Variance '12 to '13";
    rbreak after / summarize ul ol;
run;
```

This does *ALMOST* everything I want. The following things I have not been able to figure out:

1. Name the summary row 'Summary'
2. Order by descending var_12_13 so team with highest variance is first
3. I need the summary of the variance column to be the variance of the totals, not the mean of the variances (so it should be -5%)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
proc sort data=work.have; by descending var_12_13;

proc report data=have;
    column team goals_12 goals_13 var_12_13;
    define team / 'Team';
    define goals_12 / analysis '2012 Goals';
    define goals_13 / analysis '2013 Goals';
    define var_12_13 / order=data analysis format=percent. mean "Variance '12 to '13" weight=goals_13;

    compute team;
    if _BREAK_ in ('_RBREAK_') 
        then do;
            team="Summary";
        end;
    endcomp;

    rbreak after / summarize ul ol;
run;
```

Comment: This is very close.  For some reason, the -1 is not converting to (100%) for team TOT.  Also, can I format the 5% so it shows that this is a negative number?  Right now it looks like a positive variance.  Also, I thought to use proc sort, but thought there was an internal way for proc report to order by a variable.